# Button loaded from xib addTarget not performing action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm having a problem when I want to add a target to a button from a loaded xib.

I have this:

```
var cleanFilters = FilterLabelView()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationItem.title = "EXPLORE WORKOUTS"
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedBold", size: 16.0)!]
    setFilterLabel()
}

func setFilterLabel() {
    cleanFilters = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FilterLabelView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? FilterLabelView)!
    self.view.addSubview(cleanFilters)

    cleanFilters.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cleanFilters, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cleanFilters, attribute: .trailingMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 35))

    cleanFilters.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hideFilterLabel), for: .touchUpInside)
    cleanFilters.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setDefaultFilters), for: .touchUpInside)

    cleanFilters.isHidden = defaultsManager.isDefaultFilters()
    if !cleanFilters.isHidden {
        self.workoutsCollection.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}

func hideFilterLabel() {
    cleanFilters.isHidden = true
    self.workoutsCollection.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func setDefaultFilters() {
    defaultsManager.setDefaultFilters()
    cleanFilters.isHidden = true
    getAllWorkouts()
}
```

The deleteButton and confirmButton actions are not being called and I can't figure out why.

Here's the FilterLabelView I'm loading:

```
import UIKit

class FilterLabelView: UIView {
 @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var confirmButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var labelTapRecongnizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!
}
```

Comment: What's the `cleanFilters`?

Comment: The `FilterLabelView` xib I'm loading that has the buttons I'm trying to add the targets to

Comment: `var cleanFilters: FilterLabelView!` right?

Comment: It's weird you first initializing `FilterLabelView()` then loading the xib in `setFilterLabel()`. That's probably the reason. Instead of initializing just have the reference like `var cleanFilters: FilterLabelView!`

Comment: It didn't work, the targets are still not being called

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your buttons are not hidden? remember that if a button is hidden the hittest can't perform touches... is it also posible your buttons are really little or have `isUserInteractionEnabled` as false... A good way to be aware whether is a problem with the view is looking out the `Debug view hierarchy`

Comment: I looked at it and the `isUserInteractionEnabled` is true, I also tried adding a tap gesture recognizer but it didn't work.

Comment: @GuillermoAguirre can you tell us what was your solution for futures similar issues?